# Load component's language file to module form

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, translation

I have module `mod_mymodule` and it has the same translations as component `com_mycomponent`. I don't want to duplicate these same files and use only one file.

I load form from `com_mycomponent` to `mod_mymodule` and it has fields with labels like: `COM_MYCOMPONENT_TEST`. In `joomla_root/language/en-EN/en-EN.com_mycomponent.ini` I have translation to this.

I want to load `joomla_root/language/en-EN/en-EN.com_mycomponent.ini` to module. I also tried to add `JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_ritcatalogue');` in `mod_mymodule.php`. Not working. I also tried to load translations in module manifest file `mod_mymodule.xml`

```
<languages folder="language">
    <language tag="en-EN">en-EN/en-EN.com_ritcatalogue.ini</language>
    <language tag="en-EN">en-EN/en-EN.com_ritcatalogue.sys.ini</language>
</languages>
```

But my module only displays `COM_MYCOMPONENT_TEST`

Comment: Did you try https://docs.joomla.org/Loading_extra_language_files, the example actually is loading component language files in module...

Comment: Works. I use `$lang->getTag()` as $language_tag. But what if translation to this language does not exist? It should load `en-EN` translation. Actually doesn't load anything

Comment: Haven't done it myself, but I think the normal solution was to load the English translation first, and then try to load the current language. If no translation exists, nothing happens. If one exists, it overrides the english strings. Don't know if J!3 has a more sophisticated way to do this...

Comment: First load `en-EN` then `$lang->getTag()`. It loads first translation if there is no the second one. Thank you.

Comment: So did you solve your problem? If so you might want to answer your own question using your working code as an example.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->load('com_mycomponent', JPATH_SITE, 'en-GB', true);
$lang->load('com_mycomponent', JPATH_SITE, $lang->getTag(), true);
```

First we load main translation (in my case it's en-GB), then load active language. If there is no active language translation, Joomla display main translation.

***List of language tags:***
https://community.joomla.org/translations/joomla-3-translations.html